# Height and width of linear layout in android are not getting set

Tags: java, android

```
                //* Linear Layout *
            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            linearLayout.setTag("linearLayout" + Integer.toString(id));
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_border_1);
            linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 70);
            layoutParams.setMargins(20, 10, 20, 10);

            linearLayout.setWeightSum(10);
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Integer.toString((int)linearLayout.getWeightSum())+ ", " +  Integer.toString( linearLayout.getHeight()) + ", " + Integer.toString( linearLayout.getWidth()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //* Edit Text *
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            editText.setTag("editText" + Integer.toString(id));
            layoutParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            layoutParams.height = 50;
            layoutParams.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
            layoutParams.weight = 2;
            editText.setEms(10);
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            //* Text View *
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTag("textView" + Integer.toString(id));
            layoutParams.height = 50;
            layoutParams.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
            layoutParams.weight = 4;
            textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView.setText("Credit Hours");

            //* Spinner *
            Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
            spinner.setTag("spinner" + Integer.toString(id));
            layoutParams.width = 50;
            layoutParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            spinner.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            layoutParams.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
            layoutParams.weight = 4;
            spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            linearLayout.addView(editText);
            linearLayout.addView(textView);
            linearLayout.addView(spinner);

            llSubjectsContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSubjectsContainer);
            llSubjectsContainer.addView(linearLayout);
```

This is my code but it is not working as it is supposed to work. But the height nor the width of linearLayout are getting set from this code nor margins. I've already spent hours and hours on it but din't find any working solution.

Comment: Are you sure you kept this code inside onCreate() ?

Comment: no i want this to work on a button click

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you initialize the variables out side the onCreate function and use the same in other functions.

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout mLayout;    //Initialize it here

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        buttonClick();
    }

    public void buttonClick(){
        mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        mLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        //Make like this and try!
    }
}
```

Comment: This is complete code which executes on a button click! Not a single thing is missing in it related to this code.

Comment: But I am creating new LinearLayout! I'm not supposed to findViewById

Comment: Nothing happened